# Error compiling Hello World with Agda 2.5.4.2 at command line

Tags: agda

Given the following Agda program:

```
module hello-world where

open import Agda.Builtin.IO
open import Agda.Builtin.Unit
open import Agda.Builtin.String

postulate
  putStrLn : String -> ⊤

{-# FOREIGN GHC import qualified Data.Text.IO as Text #-}
{-# COMPILE GHC putStrLn = Text.putStrLn #-}

main : IO ⊤
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

I type the following at the command line:

```
agda --compile hello-world.agda
```

and get the following output:

```
Checking hello-world (C:\Projects\2019-06-14-MyAgda\hello-world.agda).
C:\Projects\2019-06-14-MyAgda\hello-world.agda:14,8-32
```

There is no .exe file in the directory where I run agda from. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I declared `putStrLn` as follows:

```
postulate
  putStrLn : String -> ⊤
```

The correct declaration is, of course

```
postulate
  putStrLn : String -> IO ⊤
```